# Processamento de arquivos de texto

Tags: c#, mvc

Eu estou processando arquivos `.txt`, porém eu processo mais de 1 arquivo por vez, mas no banco só salva 1 arquivo, debugando vejo que ele lê e processa os 2 arquivos, ou até 3 dependendo de quantos arquivos estou processando.

Segue abaixo minha `controller` e `Negocio`.

Teria que estar unindo os arquivos `.txt` para eu gerar um único relatório depois.

Antes de processar ele limpa a base de dado com método `removerSabemi()`, porém ele processa 1 arquivo e depois volta para o método `removerSabemi()`, e depois processa o outro arquivo.

Eu preciso que passe pelo método `removerSabemi()` apenas na primeira execução.

Preciso tratar de alguma forma que não estou encontrando.

**Controller**

```
if ((arquivosSabemi != null) && (arquivosSabemi.Any(f => f != null)))
{
    foreach (var arquivo in arquivosSabemi.Where(s => s.ContentLength > 0))
    {
        InstanceResolverFor<IServicoFIDC>.Instance.SalvarSabemi(arquivo.InputStream);
    }
}
```

**Serviço**

```
public void SalvarSabemi(Stream dados)
{
     using (var arquivoSabemi = new StreamReader(dados))
     {
         var dal = InstanceResolverFor<IDadosFIDC>.Instance;
         var primeiraLinha = true;
         string linha;

         dal.RemoverSabemi();
         while (!arquivoSabemi.EndOfStream && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(linha = arquivoSabemi.ReadLine()))
         {
              if (primeiraLinha) { primeiraLinha = false; continue; }

              var colunas = linha.Split("\t".ToCharArray());

              dal.Inserir(new DadosSabemi
              {
                  CEDNTE_CEDN = ParseValueOrNull<long>(colunas[0]),
```

Comment: No teu "controller", faça algo como: `InstanceResolverFor<IDadosFIDC>.Instance.RemoverSabemi();` (antes do `foreach`). E no "serviço" retire  o `dal.RemoverSabemi();`. Isso deve funcionar.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, consegui resolver com o método abaixo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta você passar um bool para seu método.

Controller

```
if ((arquivosSabemi != null) && (arquivosSabemi.Any(f => f != null)))
{
    bool ckfim = true;
    foreach (var arquivo in arquivosSabemi.Where(s => s.ContentLength > 0))
    {
        InstanceResolverFor<IServicoFIDC>.Instance.SalvarSabemi(arquivo.InputStream, ckfim);
        ckfim = false;
    }
}
```

Serviço

```
public void SalvarSabemi(Stream dados, bool ckfim)
{
     using (var arquivoSabemi = new StreamReader(dados))
     {
         var dal = InstanceResolverFor<IDadosFIDC>.Instance;
         var primeiraLinha = true;
         string linha;

         if(ckfim)
            dal.RemoverSabemi();

         while (!arquivoSabemi.EndOfStream && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(linha = arquivoSabemi.ReadLine()))
         {
              if (primeiraLinha) { primeiraLinha = false; continue; }

              var colunas = linha.Split("\t".ToCharArray());

              dal.Inserir(new DadosSabemi
              {
```

Comment: Fiz dessa forma, usando uma variavel do tipo bool para verificar o fim da Stream, porem na controller fica reclamando que o método não pode receber 2 argumentos.

Comment: Resolveu aqui, eu tinha esquecido de passar a variavel na interface tambem, e com isso só podia receber 1 argumento. 
Obrigado cara, me ajudou bastante.